# PHP/MySQL - Join/Union the results of two tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

this is my first post on Stack Overflow, so I'll try to provide as much information as possible. I've spent hours trying to figure this out, and thought that maybe some help would get me over the hump with this project.

I'm trying to create a review site using Mysql 5/Php5 and I have two tables:

'**companies**'
'**reviews**'

In the **companies** table, I have a full list of all US companies, and in the **reviews** table, I have a list of reviews based on companies from the "**companies**" table. The **reviews** table is populated when users submits a review via a form.

Thus, I want to have a search results page, that will list all companies by alphabet. In the table for the search results, the company name would be listed, the total reviews, and the total score.

In the **companies** table, I have the following columns:
**company_id

company

address

city

state**

In the **reviews** table, I have the following columns:
**'review_id'

'review_date'

'company'

'review'

'review_city'

'review_state'

'comp_benefits'

'work_life_balance'

'job_security'

'career_growth'**

Currently, I wrote a SQL script that outputs all companies from the '**review**' table, a sum of it's score and a total review count:

> $result = mysql_query('select *, SUM(comp_benefits + work_life_balance
>   + job_security + career_growth) as ItemSum, COUNT(company) as TotalReviews from reviews where company LIKE "'.$letter.'%" GROUP BY
>   company;');

So, output would be as such:

"Best Buy" "35" "3"

The problem is, this query only outputs and counts the companies that actually have a review in the **reviews** table. My goal is to be also combine the results with the '**companies**' table, so that companies that don't have a review, still show up in the outputted list in the table, with a '**0**' for '**ItemSum**' and a '**0**' for **count**.

"ABC Company" "0" "0"
"Best Buy" "35" "3"

I have researched unions and joins, but so far, I can't find a way to output all the companies in my list, by distinct name and total count.

If anyone has any direction on this, I would very much appreciate any advice.

Comment: I'd recommend to experiment in some interactive MySQL client, not through PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query over companies with LEFT JOIN to query for COUNT:

e.g.

```
SELECT c.*, COALESCE(x.cnt, 0) 
FROM companies c 
   LEFT JOIN 
   ( 
       SELECT company, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
       FROM reviews 
       GROUP BY company 
   ) x ON x.company = c.company_id 
WHERE c.company LIKE '%...%'
```

With LEFT JOIN you combine all the records from the left (first) table - here, companies, with records from the second table (here - x). Of course '%...%' is put for example :)

Answer (score 1):

1.) You should change the column "Company" on the reviews table to be a foriegn key to company_id on the companies table.  It appears to just be by name right now. This will facilitate joins, and allow constraints.

2.) You likely want a LEFT OUTER JOIN which will give you all the rows from the first table (in this case the companies)

 

    <strike>SELECT * 
 
    FROM Companies c 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews r 

    ON c.company_id = r.company_id</strike> 


EDIT: Vassilen's join is correct, not mine.  You need to summarize the reviews rows first, instead of matching row for row.

```
SELECT c.company, COALESCE(r.total_score,0) as total_score, r.count
FROM Companies c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
( 
    SELECT company_id, SUM(comp_benefits + work_life_balance + job_security + career_growth) as total_score, COUNT(*) as count
    FROM reviews 
    GROUP BY company
) r
ON r.company_id = c.company_id
```

3.) Do you want the total score to be the sum of all the reviews? As I read it a company with 100 reviews that are poor would beat a company with one good review...